# Bloc pattern not getting notes without passing through Database

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart, async-await, bloc

I have a **working** flutter app that works with **bloc** and **SQflite** in order to fetch some notes from the database and display them in a simple ViewList. In order to better understand bloc patter i want to "eliminate" the database part and substitute the notes fetched from the db with a hardcoded list of notes written by me.
(I think the only meaningful file is the note_bloc.dart but in case I will post the remaining code)
So the code that implements the note_bloc patter and perfectly works is this:

```
class NotesBloc implements BlocBase {

final _notesController = StreamController<List<Note>>.broadcast();

StreamSink<List<Note>> get _inNotes => _notesController.sink;

Stream<List<Note>> get notes => _notesController.stream;

 NotesBloc() {
    getNotes();

}

@override
void dispose() {
    _notesController.close();
}

Future<void> getNotes()  async {
   List<Note> notesFromDB = await DBProvider.db.getNotes();
    _inNotes.add(notesFromDB);
}
```

the function DBProvider.db.getNotes() is written like this (only to know):

```
getNotes() async {
   final db = await database;
   var res = await db.query('note');
   List<Note> notes = res.isNotEmpty ? res.map((note) => Note.fromJson(note)).toList() : [];

    return notes;
}
```

the first thing I  tried to do was to  change the getNotes function of the notes_bloc like this:

```
void getNotes() async {
// List<Note> notesFromDB = await DBProvider.db.getNotes();
List<Note> noteHardcoded = [new Note()];
_inNotes.add(noteHardcoded);
```

}

good and easy but if i launch the app it gets no error and falls in a infinite loop getting no notes to display...

If instead i simply get hardcoded notes from a async function like this:

```
void getNotes() async {
// List<Note> notesFromDB = await DBProvider.db.getNotes();
List<Note> noteHardcoded = await asyncNotes();
_inNotes.add(noteHardcoded);
}

asyncNotes() async {
List<Note> noteHardcoded = [new Note()];

return noteHardcoded;
}
```

It works with no problem as expected!!
It's like getNotes() of the notes_bloc can only featch note from a ASYNC function and i cannot figure out why..

This is the statefull widget code where i use my notes_bloc:

```
class _NotesPageState extends State<NotesPage> {
NotesBloc _notesBloc;

@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();

    print("I'm in the initState going to assign _notesBlock");
    _notesBloc = BlocProvider.of<NotesBloc>(context);
    print("I'm in the initState and i assigned _notesBlock");


}
StreamBuilder<List<Note>>(
                            stream: _notesBloc.notes,
                            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Note>> snapshot) {
                              print("building context..");
                                // Make sure data exists and is actually loaded
                                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                    // If there are no notes (data), display this message.
                                    if (snapshot.data.length == 0) {
                                        return Text('No notes');
                                    }

                                    List<Note> notes = snapshot.data;

                                    return ListView.builder(
                                        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                            Note note = notes[index];

                                            return GestureDetector(
                                                onTap: () {
                                                    _navigateToNote(note);
                                                },
                                                child: Container(
                                                    height: 40,
                                                    child: Text(
                                                        'Note ' + note.id.toString(),
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                            fontSize: 18
                                                        ),
                                                    ),
                                                ),
                                            );
                                        },
                                    );
                                }


                                return Center(
                                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you calling the bloc getNotes() function on your widget.

Maybe you are adding the information on the Stream before entering the widget, so when you build your widget there's no value on your stream.

One thing you can try is to use BehaviorSubject and not Stream. BehaviorSubject always send the last sinked value, so if my hipothesis is correct it should work.

Comment: Thank you ! the problem was exactly the one you mentioned.
With a async await function the widget first go through the initState, then build the first "blank " context and then (when it receives the notes through the stream ) finally render the widget again with the notes displayed.
Without the async function it gets the notes right after the initialization of the bloc (_notesBloc) ,in the initState function , so when the real context rendering happen no notes are received and indeed displayed.